# Google docs - automated List of tables

Tags: google-docs, caption, tableofcontents

Is it  possible to add `captions` to tables in Google docs?

I would like to be able to produce an automated **list of tables**. 
For example something like this :

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: Can't you just merge the 3 columns for the first row?

Answer (score 4):

The [Caption Maker Add-on](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/caption_maker/525661240172?hl=en&pann=cwsdp) detects figures and tables in a Google Doc, puts numbered captions above or below them and creates lists of figures and tables that can even be updated as the document evolves.

Comment: Since yesterday, this add-on seems to be gone from the GSuite Marketplace. Today is submission day. =(

Answer (score 1):

The "Captionizer" Addon seems to be able to do this now, albeit without page numbering. The creator says there is no way to lookup the page number in a google doc to be able to add that feature.

[Captionizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/captionizer/deemabgnpoamameafiackibdmgbloimo?hl=en%22Captionizer%22)

Comment: Currently, this add-on seems to be blocked because it accesses private data.

Answer (score 0):

As @Falko Menge suggested in the first response Caption Maker appears to be the best option. The app went down for some time, but now you can install it without problems from google marketplace.

Caption Maker is available here: https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/caption_maker/226603355104

It seems to be working just fine.

Cheers!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The answer you refer to (though "first" is not a relaiable reference because display order is individually configurabel...) already provides a link. So what is the additional value your post contributes? Also, I do not understand "I went down for some time".

Comment: edited, fast english, sorry. The contribute is the app link that was not available in previous posts. Plus, an app that covers the features described in the question. Cheers.